# preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript

```
//prevent default handler
function click_handler(event){            
  if(event.shiftKey){
      event.preventDefault();
  }
}
//event listener
var file_mgmt=document.querySelector('div.filemanager'); 
if(window.addEventListener){
        file_mgmt.addEventListener('click',click_handler,false);
    }else if(window.attachEvent){
        file_mgmt.attachEvent('onclick',click_handler);
    }else{
        file_mgmt.onclick=click_handler;
    }
```

basically file_mgmt is a div container which is enclosed with  tag linking to another links. Since Shift+click opens the link in new _blank tab i want to prevent it since it will damage the original page layout.

Giving up after a while, i even tried following from Mozilla doc:[Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), the result being the same.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: if it's a `click` event its `event.shiftKey` very likely evaluates to `false`, so you'll not get into your `if`... capture the `shiftKey` event in some state variable!

Comment: try **file_mgmt.addEventListener('click',click_handler,true);** make usercapture flag true also see **Event type** returned

Comment: soo......... any suggestion on what i should do?

Comment: Thanks guys big help! I forgot about the third parameter so idiotic

Answer (score 1):

Preventing default action when clicking on a div will not do anything since by default it doesn't do anything anyway. 
You should attach the click handler to the actual link instead.

Comment: the div is like this <a><div></div></a> so no your argument is wrong